# If $\sum{a_{n^2}}$ converges, then $\sum a_n \frac{1}{n}$ also converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to determine whether the following statement is true or false:

> Let $a_n$ be a non increasing sequence.
>
> If $\sum{a_{n^2}}$ converges, then $\sum a_n \frac{1}{n}$ also
> converges.

By examining a few examples the statement seems correct (I did not managed to find a counter example).

But im having some hard time proving this statement.

Any tips will be useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necessarily $a_n\ge0$, and $\frac1na_n$ is weakly descreasing and non-negative. By Cauchy condensation $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1ka_k$ converges if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2^k}$ converges. Since eventually $k^2\le 2^k$, we have $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2^k}\le C+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k^2}<\infty$$

Comment: So simple and elegant! 
Cauchy condedsation test was the last thing on my mind. how did you manage to think of it?

Comment: @idoeido I want to say that I check all the ideas I know and inspect only the ones that are promising, but the truth is that when it happens fast, as it should, it's hard to tell for sure. Here it was easy because it's an exercise and the hypothesis were there.

Comment: Exercises are not easy in general. But @idoeido there's motivation from the classic method for showing the series of $1/n$ diverges